# >net Assembly Public Key generation

Tags: c#

suppose i have created the C# class lib,now if i look on to the assembly information of my classlib then the Public key value is null.. plz tell be bot can i gene

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/03/22/finding-the-public-key-of-an-assembly.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the public key (token) is null, it's probably because you did not signed it (it has no "strong name"). you can follow these links for some help: [How to: Sign an Assembly with a Strong Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx) or (more ancient): [How To Create an Assembly with a Strong Name in .NET Framework SDK](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302340/en-us)

Comment: Thankx Alot I have Done this...But Now I am in one more problem.how to Specify the Public key in internalvisibleto Attribute... i am doing in this way [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("WFP1, PubicKey=f11cfa1421bb9e53")]

Comment: Two links for InternalsVisibleTo: http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2005/05/10/internalsvisibleto-sn and http://geekswithblogs.net/jwhitehorn/archive/2007/11/09/116750.aspx

Comment: its solved actually i was putting the publickeytoken in publickey,its solved thankx alot for ur help